# Getting this error using Entity Framework Navigation Properties

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I am getting this error

> The entity type
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserRole' to which
>   the navigation property 'Roles' refers does not derive from the type
>   'SafeWare.Models.ApplicationUserRole' on which the inverse navigation
>   property 'User' is declared.

while calling

```
    bool ret = _userManager.Users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserName == userName) != null;
```

This function tests to see is a User exists.

Here are my objects:

```
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
{
    public ApplicationRole() : base()
    {
        Users = new HashSet<ApplicationUserRole>();
    }
    public ApplicationRole(string name, string description) : base(name)
    {
        this.Description = description;
    }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Role")]
    [DisplayName("Users")]
    public new virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> Users { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }

    public ApplicationUser()
    {
        FileUploads = new HashSet<FileUpload>();
        Roles = new HashSet<ApplicationUserRole>();
    }


    [InverseProperty("User")]
    [DisplayName("Roles")]
    public new virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole
{
    public ApplicationUserRole()
    {
    }

    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public virtual ApplicationRole Role { get; set; }

}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("AspNetUsers");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationRole>().HasKey<string>(r => r.Id).ToTable("AspNetRoles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUserRole>().HasKey(r => new { r.UserId, r.RoleId }).ToTable("AspNetUserRoles");

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasMany(u => u.Roles).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(ur => ur.User).WillCascadeOnDelete(value: false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationRole>().HasMany(r => r.Users).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(ur => ur.Role).WillCascadeOnDelete(value: false);

        //modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationRole>().HasMany<ApplicationUserRole>((ApplicationRole u) => u.Users);
        //modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasMany<ApplicationUserRole>((ApplicationUser u) => u.Roles);
    }
}
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

The [Inverse Properties](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inverseproperty-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx) attribute i.e. `[InverseProperty("User")]` and `[InverseProperty("Role")]` declare properties of type `ICollection<ApplicationUserRole>` but they point to properties of type `ApplicationUser` and `ApplicationRole` on the `ApplicationUserRole` class.

For example ,

```
[InverseProperty("User")]
[DisplayName("Roles")]
public new virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> Roles { get; set; }
```

points to

```
[ForeignKey("Id")]
public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
```

which is of type `ApplicationUser` and not `ApplicationUserRole`

Have you tried removing the `InverseProperty` attribute?

---

Should it not be `public override ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> Roles { get; }` if you are looking to override the base `Roles` method.

Personally I would pass the type to the base class `IdentityUser<TKey, TLogin, TRole, TClaim> : IUser<TKey>` instead of overriding the `Roles` method in `IdentityUser` method

e.g. `ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<TKey, TLogin, ApplicationUserRole, TClaim>`

The same principle can be applied to other identity models e.g. `ApplicationRole`

Comment: I just can't see what I'm doing wrong.  The IdentityUserRole declaration uses the ApplicationRole and ApplicationUser types. Now, this was the older version of Identity that has been removed.